# Can't upload image to Firebase Storage from flutter web

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

so i tried this to get an image and upload it:

```
var file;
      html.InputElement uploadInput = html.FileUploadInputElement()
        ..accept = "image/*";
      uploadInput.click();
      uploadInput.onChange.listen((event) {
        file = uploadInput.files.first;
        final reader = html.FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
        reader.onLoadEnd.listen((event) async {
          print("done");
          StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
              .ref()
              .child('${widget.uid}/${DateTime.now()}');
          StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putData(file);
          await uploadTask.onComplete;
          print('File Uploaded');
          print(storageReference.path);
          storageReference.getDownloadURL().then((fileURL) {
            setState(() {
              _uploadedFileURL = fileURL;
              
            });
          });
        });
      });
```

as shown in a tutorial,however the guy use .put() and not putData() but it's now deprecated, so when using .put() i get:

> Expected a value of type 'File', but got one of type 'File$'

and with .putData() i get:

> Expected a value of type 'Uint8List', but got one of type 'File$'

Any ideas how i could convert File$ or directly import a File or Uint8List from the user from Flutter Web?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)` and `storageReference.putData(reader.result)`.